# IOS google map clustering (grouping) big amount of markers

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have an ios app which displays a lot of markers on ios google maps. Is there any ready solution for this problem but for Google Map, not another maps?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no there isn't ready made code. we wrote our own solution and I know of a few other ones.. the MAP you use really doesn't matter.

the grouping can happen 'on the model'

Answer (score 0):

you can use REMarkerClusterer library.

> REMarkerClusterer was inspired by the Apple Photos app on the iPhone

**it provides nice animation for grouping and ungrouping marker**

https://github.com/romaonthego/REMarkerClusterer